# How to write common code for Jenkins Pipelines

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to know how one would write common code that is used by other var files. Any pointers to decent tutorials would be appreciated as I'm sure I will be writing many more modules. I have been trying to follow this: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#writing-libraries but have very little knowledge of groovy.

From what I understand, files in `var/` are loaded and are available within the pipeline syntax. Files located in `src/` need to be imported by the files in `var/` to be used. Is this correct?

I would like to produce the following:

1. A file that has common code such as AWS Account numbers, functions like ECR logins and a ECR string creator which requires the account number. I foresee many other common aws tasks living in here.
2. A file that has a list of commands to execute to do the work I want to do.

What I have currently (doesn't work):

```java
// var/ECRPush.groovy
@Library('awsCommon')
import com.mycompany.awsCommon

def call(Map config=[:]) {
  awsCommon.dockerLogin(config.account)
  ecrAddress=awsCommon.ecrAddress(account:config.account, name:config.name) + ":" + config.tag
  sh("docker tag ${config.sourceContainer} ${ecrAddress}")
  sh("docker push ${ecrAddress}")
}
```

```java
// src/com/mycompany/awsCommon/awsCommon.groovy
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
package com.mycomany.awsCommon

class awsCommon {
  def Map accounts = [
    "dev":"123",
    "shared":"456"
  ]

  // used as:
  // account: account from accounts
  // name: 'service'
  def String ecrAddress(Map config=[:]) {
    address = self.Accounts([config.account]) + ".dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/" + config.name
    return address
  }

  def dockerLogin(String account) {
    switch(account) {
      case "shared":
        echo 'login to Shared ECR'
        withCredentials([aws(credentialsId: 'jenkins-aws-shared')]){
          sh '$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1)'
        }
        break
      case "dev":
        echo 'login to Dev ECR'
        withCredentials([aws(credentialsId: 'jenkins-aws-dev')]){
          sh '$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1)'
        }
        break
    }
  }
}
```

```java
// Example desired usage
@Library('jenkins-shared-lib-global') _
pipeline {
  stage('ecr push') {
    steps {
      ECRPush(
        account: 'dev',
        name: 'ecs-testing',
        sourceContainer: 'ecs-testing:dev',
        tag: 'jenkins'
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" We would need more information than that to assist. Additionally, I do notice your global variable method is missing some kind of initialization with a constructor for your class, so that would be a good first issue to fix and see if that moves you forward. Note also that AWS and Docker pipeline plugins already exist with the functionality your code is implementing.